# Delphi Execute applications

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to create a dll with delphi, I set some file attributes but then I want to run a .exe file from the working directory.
I tried to run the exe file with this code

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'start.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But I get errors:
Undeclared identifier 'Handle'.

Undeclared identifier 'SW_SHOWNORMAL'

What would be the best way to run the exe file ?

Answer (score 10):

Be sure to add ShellApi to your Unit's uses clause.

```
uses ShellApi;
```

The first parameter can be 0 if the program doesn't have a windows handle.

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', ('start.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
```

The "Handle" parameter is not defined in your start.exe procedure

```
Procedure TForm1.StartEXE;
begin
ShellExecute(0, 'open', ('start.exe'), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

This will make it universally-accessible from any other function or procedure within your TForm1.

Answer (score 7):

The errors you describe in the question are:

> Undeclared identifier 'Handle'

Only you know which handle to pass. Either pass a handle to a form, or the `Application` object's handle, or perhaps even `0` if your application does not have a window handle to hand.

> Undeclared identifier 'SW_SHOWNORMAL'

That symbol is defined in the `Windows` unit. You simply need to add that unit to your `uses` list.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Windows` unit to the implementation clause of your unit where this call is made and your program will compile. ALthough the `CreateProcess` function would be a better option in this case. Something like this (not tested and off the top of my head) :-

```
Procedure ExecNewProcess(Const ProgramName : String; pWait : Boolean);
Var
  lOK : Boolean;
  lStartInfo : TStartupInfo;
  lProcInfo : TProcessInformation;
Begin
  FillChar(lStartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
  FillChar(lProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);
  lStartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  lOK := CreateProcess(Nil, PChar(ProgramName), Nil, Nil, False,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, Nil, Nil, lStartInfo, lProcInfo);
  If lOK Then
  Begin
    If pWait Then
      WaitForSingleObject(lProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
  End
  Else
    ShowMessage('Unable to run ' + ProgramName);
  CloseHandle(lProcInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(lProcInfo.hThread);
End;
```

Comment: and how to use the CreateProcess function in this case ?

Comment: @Dany Seems to be a new question?

Comment: @Dany I amended my answer to include an (untested) example of CreateProcess.

Comment: `lProcInfo` is an out parameter; hence no need to initialise it. What's more, the second parameter of `CreateProcess` must be a modifiable string. You get away with it in D7 because you call the ANSI API which happens to let you off, but it's best practise to pass a modifiable string.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't realise it needed to be modifiable. Can't think why it would need to be either, but every day's a school day!

Comment: Because `CreateProcessW` uses the buffer you provide as its workspace for parsing the string. You get away with it in `CreateProcessA` because that is a wrapper around `CreateProcessW` and `CreateProcessA` creates a modifiable buffer to pass to `CreateProcessW`. That's all implementation detail though, and the docs are clear. It's a very common mistake. Results in AV when you call the Unicode version. Copy the string to a local variable and call `UniqueString` on it. Job done.